# Copying contents of text file using file handling

Tags: c, file-io

I created a text file named "`test.txt`" and then executed this program to copy the contents of "`test.txt`" to "`file.txt`". But it is showing an error while opening the file itself, i.e., `fr==NULL` is true.

What is wrong with the program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int i,count=0;
   char ch;
   FILE *fw,*fr;
   fw = fopen("file.txt", "a+");
   fr = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
   fseek(fr,0,SEEK_SET);
   if(fr==NULL)
   {
     printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
     exit(0);
   }
   while((ch=getc(fr))!=EOF)
   {
     putc(ch,fw);
   }
   fclose(fw);
   fclose(fr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't matter i think or does it?

Comment: Is `"test.txt"` Read-Only file?

Comment: no,it is not read-only

Answer (score 0):

If `fopen` returns `NULL`, check the value of `errno`, e.g. by including `<errno.h>` and using the `perror("Error while opening the file");` instead of the `printf` statement.

Comment: It is showing error while opening the file:Invalid argument.What does this mean?